# Is it possible to show the app UI portion of iOS sharing extension into a page control in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller, pagecontrol

I am using the following code to share text using iOS sharing extension (UIActivityViewController).

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["File URL"], applicationActivities: [])
presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It shows a popup to share using text sharing applications like following:

[image]

But, I want the sharing app portion in my view into a page control like below:

[image]

How can I do this? If there is any alternative way to achieve this requirement, kindly suggest.